# Update & delete Items in open-source QuickBooks PHP DevKit on GitHub

Tags: quickbooks

I am using the open-source `QuickBooks` `PHP` DevKit on `GitHub`.
I added an Item  using the example `example_items_add.php`.
How can I update & delete an item?
Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updating Items:**

Updating items is very similar to adding them - just call `->update(...)` instead of calling `->add(...)`.

You can see an example here:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/example_item_update.php

The code looks like:

```
// Get the existing item 
$items = $ItemService->query($Context, $realm, "SELECT * FROM Item WHERE Id = '2' ");
$Item = $items[0];

// Update the name of the item
$Item->setName($Item->getName() . ' ' . mt_rand(0, 1000));

if ($resp = $ItemService->update($Context, $realm, $Item->getId(), $Item))
{
    print('Updated the item name to ' . $Item->getName());
}
```

**Deleting Items:**

Per [Intuit's documentation](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting/0300_developer_guides/0015_calling_data_services#/Deleting_an_object), items don't really support true deletes.

Instead, you mark them as "inactive" so that they no longer show up in the UI. This is as simple as making an item *update*, and setting the `Active` flag to `false`.

`$Item->setActive(false);`

Comment: I used this code for update. But I am getting Fatal error & the error is "Fatal error:  Call to undefined method QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Item::update()". Please help.

Comment: Make sure you have the latest code from GitHub. You're not using the latest code.

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr, where can I find the list of QB API actions such as `->setDisplayName()` on vendors? Their documentation sucks. I'm looking to update vendor address information, is it all keyed like `->set[ObjectPropertyName]`?

Comment: The method names literally map exactly to the property names in Intuit's docs -- so ->setGivenName($v) ->getGivenName(); ->setDisplayName($v); ->getDisplayName(); etc. etc. etc.